# two tab bar in ionic- one top and other at bottom?

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am creating an [ionic](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/) app using tabs. I want to use two different tab bars. One placed at top and other placed at bottom. The ionic tabs tutorial has default tabs position to top for android platform. The tabs can be positioned at the bottom with the following line in config section

$ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('bottom');

I have no idea about how to add two tab-bars and position one at top and other at bottom. Need your valuable feedback.
The config section code is as follows

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
    // for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      // org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$ionicConfigProvider) {

  $ionicConfigProvider.tabs.position('bottom');

  // Ionic uses AngularUI Router which uses the concept of states
  // Learn more here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router
  // Set up the various states which the app can be in.
  // Each state's controller can be found in controllers.js
  $stateProvider

  // setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
    url: '/tab',
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/tabs.html'
  })

  // Each tab has its own nav history stack:

  .state('tab.dash', {
    url: '/dash',
    views: {
      'tab-dash': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-dash.html'
      }
    }
  })

  .state('tab.lights', {
      url: '/lights',
      views: {
        'tab-lights': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/tab-lights.html'
        }
      }
    })

 .state('tab.account', {
    url: '/account',
    views: {
      'tab-account': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/tab-account.html'
      }
    }
  });

  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/tab/dash');

});
```

The tabs.html is as follows

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-color-active-positive">

  <!-- Dashboard Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Status" icon-off="ion-ios-pulse" icon-on="ion-ios-pulse-strong" href="#/tab/dash">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-dash"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <!-- Lights Tab -->
  <ion-tab title="Lights" icon-off="ion-ios-chatboxes-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-chatboxes" href="#/tab/lights">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-lights"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

  <!-- AccountTab -->
  <ion-tab title="Account" icon-off="ion-ios-chatboxes-outline" icon-on="ion-ios-chatboxes" href="#/tab/account">
    <ion-nav-view name="tab-account"></ion-nav-view>
  </ion-tab>

</ion-tabs>
```

Comment: Well I suggest you to make a codepen of your code and share it here with the code of the other bar you want to add.

Comment: As i mentioned, i have no idea about creating two tab-bars. One tab bar code is posted here. For second tab-bar, do i need to add another ion-tabs tag in tabs.html file?

Comment: http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#tabs just add one of these in your view manually and bind them with ng-click.